# How to handle all other addresses in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to handle all the address which I didn't make a specific function for.

For example,

```
@GetMapping({"/"}) // handles "/"
public String main(Model model) {
    return "homepage";
}
@GetMapping({"/admin"}) // handles "/admin"
public String main(Model model) {
    return "admin";
}
```

How can I handle all the other address, such as "/asdf" etc and send them all to a specific page?

Comment: Did you try `/**`?

Comment: It would be cleaner to let Spring return a 404 instead

Comment: I tried the ```/**``` method, but now my website doesn't loads the images (stored locally in the static folder) @peterulb

Answer (score 0):

You can use @[PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) for this.

```
@GetMapping("/{var}") // handles any string you can pass
public String main(@PathVariable(value="var",required=true)String var) {
    return "anyString";
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but now my website doesn't loads the images (stored locally in the static folder)

Comment: Well, I am not sure if not loading images has something to do with introducing of this method.

Comment: Accessing images in my site is by localhost:port/image.jpg etc, and it fails....

Comment: In that case you have to append static path something like `@GetMapping("/handleanyString/{var}")` .  And your request will looks like `/handleanyString/asdff`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help you:

```
@GetMapping("/{whatever}")
public void xxx(@PathVariable String whatever) {
    // Do things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String fallback(){
return "specific-page";
}
```

Just make sure that this is your last RequestMapping, I remember that in node.js it has weird results until it was placed on the bottom of the class, so just to be safe, but it on the bottom as well in your java class.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write custom exception handler, where you will place logic that will execute when user tries to go to path that doesn't exist.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAOP {


    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e)   {
        // when some other exception occures, you can handle it here..
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e)   {
        //do whatever you want, return some page..
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use wildcards like this

```
@GetMapping("/**")
public String handle() {
    return handleException(exception, "404");
}
```

but I think it is more elegant to catch it as a 404 error and then you can continue  as you like

```
 @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class){
  public ModelAndView handlePageNotFoundException(final Exception exception) {
    return handleException(exception, "404");
  }
```